# rs422/485 maximum terminator resistor value

Tags: resistors, rs485, termination, rs422

as i know terminator resistor value is ~120ohm. But i found a circuit that has 10kohm terminator resitor at A and B lines. In circuit transeiver IC is SP3485E. What is the reason for 10k ?

That is the photo. You can see pins 7 & 6 have 10k

[image]

Comment: How do you know that a termination resistor isn't applied at the connector or external to what your picture shows. The picture explains nothing. A circuit is what I asked for and that means a schematic.

Comment: i have no schematic but i guaranteed this is termination resistor. R59 and R58 bias resistors. After termination resistor there is 712 which is rs485 tvs diode. After that there are fuses absolutely resettable than it goes to connector.

Comment: Get out your meter, study the PCB artwork and reconstruct the circuit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those aren't termination resistors. The 10k, along with the 51k to either side, are a bias network that keeps the bus in a known state whenever all drivers are tristated, minimizing unwanted transitions on the receivers.

Comment: for 51k okey i agree these are pull up and pull down resistors for fail safe but when we put the resistor between A-B lines it works like a terminator am i wrong ? For example
https://www.mikrocontroller.net/attachment/38973/FailSafe.jpg

Comment: Yes, the 10k is in the same position that a termination would be, but with such a high value, it does not function as a terminator for a 120-ohm bus.

Answer (score 2):

The termination resistor is not determined by the 485 transceiver I.C.  It is a transmission line termination.  It's value is intended to match the characteristic impedance of the transmission line.  The twisted pair cable used for EIA/485 or RS485 has a characteristic impedance of 120 ohms.  Terminating the two ends of that cable with a resistor equal to its characteristic impedance prevents reflections due to fast pulses.

If this same cable is terminated with 10k ohms, depending on its length, high speed pulses will have reflections that could appear as noise and signal distortion. Operating at very low baud will minimize this problem.

Comment: If the line is very short (cm) then termination is not too important

Comment: First of all, thx for your reply.i know termination resistor is not determined by IC. i gave the name of IC for extra.  Baudrate 250000 bps and max length is 300m limited so thats is Not too much.  When i investigate different circuits for the same purpose there is not 10k resistor.

Comment: Raising the termination resistor to 10k will certainly reduce power consumption...important for battery powered devices.  I have done similar in the past, but operated at much lower baud to prevent reflections.  If you want to test with the 10k term., I suggest you look at the line with a scope while signal of interest is present.  Remember though, this is differential so you must connect your scope accordingly.

Comment: Hmm. it is a new for me. as you say i must scope it. So if it reduces the power consumption may it decrases or limits common mode range from [-7,12V] to (etc.) [-5,+7]  ?

Comment: Common mode range is set by the SP3485.  See the datasheet.

Comment: Looking at the photo you added, I suspect the 10k is simply to provide a termination for when no cable/load is connected.  Often with 485 arrangements, the D-Connector has the termination included along with a switch to enable/disable the termination resistor.